# How can we switch to normal tokenizer instead of subword tokenizer in Huggingface?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I am working on a token classification problem using m-bert model. I am using the default tokenizer using the following piece of code :

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
```

With the above piece of code, the default subword-based tokenizer is loaded but I want to switch to a normal word-based tokenizer. Please guide on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible because the model expects subwords and is unaware of any words that are not part of the tokenizer's vocabulary. As you can see in the following example, the subwords are mapped to the embedding layer of the corresponding model (i.e. sub word with id `34` will be used to retrieve the embedding vector with id 34 from the embedding layer):

```py
from transformers   import BertTokenizer, BertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")

print(model.embeddings.word_embeddings)
print(tokenizer.vocab_size)
```

Output:

```
Embedding(105879, 768, padding_idx=0)
105879
```

I assume you are asking this question because you are facing the problem that the parts of an actual word are classified differently. You can use the TokenClassification pipeline with the [aggregation strategy simple](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline.aggregation_strategy) for that:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline

model_location = ""

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_location)
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_location)

p = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")
sample = "blabla"

result = p(sample)
```